# Need help writing IF Statement

Tags: excel, if-statement

I need some help. I rarely use IF statements in excel, I usually do Index Matches, VLookups etc. So when I came across this, I thought I could come here for some help.

I want to have an IF statement that returns 5 values.

In the picture attached, you'll see 5 levels.

- If the value is less than or 0 then 5.
- If the value is 0.01 - 5.99 then 4.
- If the value is 6 - 12.99 then 3.
- If the value is 13 - 29.99 then 2.
- If the value is 30 or more then 1.

If anyone can help mem with this, that would be amazing!

Thank You!

[image: Level Chart For IF Statement]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is what you need:

```
=IF(A8<=0,5,VLOOKUP(A8,$A$1:$B$4,2,TRUE))
```

[image: spreadsheet]

Answer (score 0):

I would just go with a vlookup like so:

```
=vlookup(D2,A4:B8,2,1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a nested if formula and using the data set shown in the image of your question, then this will work:

```
   =IF(A8=B1,A1,IF(OR(A8=B2,A8<=C2),A2,IF(OR(A8=B3,A8<=C3),A3,IF(OR(A8=B4,A8<=C4),A4,IF(A8=B5,A5,"Out of Range")))))
```

In this formula, I have used cell A8 as the reference value.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change the direction of your data, then using a nested if statement like the below should work:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use the lookup table, then will be easier to use the `LOOKUP` function with constants:

```
=LOOKUP(A1,{0,0.01,6,13,30},{5,4,3,2,1})
```

[image]